# Is there a problem rounding numbers with the calculator package?

Tags: calculations

I am using the calculator package to round a number and am having trouble in some cases. Is there an issue with what I am doing?

I have included a MWE, uncommenting the line which rounds 0.0 will prevent the document from compiling. Perhaps this is just my machine or set-up?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{calculator}

\begin{document}

    % This is OK
    \ROUND[2]{1.2}{\A}
    The value of A is: \A

    % This is also OK
    \ROUND[2]{0}{\B}
    The value of B is: \B

    % This line kills it
    %\ROUND[2]{0.0}{\C}
    %The value of C is: \C

\end{document}
```

The output of this is as expected:

[image: Output with killer line commented]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is in the internal macro `\@@TRUNCATE`, which should use the parsed integer part when it is the same as the input value:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{calculator}
\makeatletter
\def\@@TRUNCATE[#1]#2#3{%
    \begingroup
    \INTEGERPART{#2}{\cctr@tempa}%
    \ifdim \cctr@tempa\p@ = #2\p@
       \expandafter\@@@TRUNCATE\cctr@tempa.00000)[#1]{#3}% Change here
    \else
       \expandafter\@@@TRUNCATE#200000.)[#1]{#3}%
    \fi
    \@OUTPUTSOL{#3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    % This is OK
    \ROUND[2]{1.2}{\A}
    The value of A is: \A

    % This is also OK
    \ROUND[2]{0}{\B}
    The value of B is: \B

    % This line kills it
    \ROUND[2]{0.0}{\C}
    The value of C is: \C

\end{document}
```

(There are also stray spaces in the definition: I've removed them.)

An alternative using `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-integer-to-decimal}
\begin{document}

    % This is OK
    The value of A is: \num{1.2}

    % This is also OK
    The value of B is:  \num{0}

    % This line kills it
    The value of C is:  \num{0.0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, the rounding method in `calculator` is horrible ...

Comment: Excellent! I should have mentioned in the question that I am using the number in a calculation (actually in TiKz) so don't want to typeset the number.
The solution involving siunitx is good, though I use it for typeset numbers as well, and may well want to change the rounding. Would you recommend any other packages?

Comment: @Sam If you are doing calculations, I'd just use `xfp` and for example `\fpeval{round(<number>,2)}` directly where you want the number.